# Joining left and right

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

I have a query that return the following data from two different tables using `eqjoin`. What I would like to combine `left` and `right`, but instead of doing a `zip()` (that rewrites the `name` and `joined_at`), I want to add the right object's properties to left one into a property named `server_info` and also delete the 'left' and make it a single object like after a `zip` operation, how can I do this directly in the query.

**Current result**

```
[{
    "left":{
       "avatar":"a29f54048d9ec6c00913057333160a3e",
       "joined_at":"Thu Feb 25 2016 21:29:07 GMT+00:00",
       "name":"Zephy",
       "uid":"132166948359241728"
    },
    "right":{
       "icon":"2aab26934e72b4ec300c5aa6cf67c7b3",
       "id":"81384788765712384",
       "member_count":7888,
       "name":"Discord API",
       "owner_id":"53905483156684800",
    }
}]
```

**Expected result**

```
[{
    "avatar":"a29f54048d9ec6c00913057333160a3e",
    "joined_at":"Thu Feb 25 2016 21:29:07 GMT+00:00",
    "name":"Zephy",
    "uid":"132166948359241728"
    "server_info": {
       "icon":"2aab26934e72b4ec300c5aa6cf67c7b3",
       "id":"81384788765712384",
       "member_count":7888,
       "name":"Discord API",
       "owner_id":"53905483156684800",
    }
}]
```

Comment: can you show the expected output in this case?

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz Updated post with expected result.

Comment: What query are you using?

Comment: `r.db("Discord").table("users").filter({
        uid: '132166948359241728'
    }).map(function(users) {
        return users.merge({
            roles: users("roles").map(function(role) {
                return r.db("Discord").table("roles").get(role)
            })
        });
}).eqJoin('serverID', r.db("Discord").table('servers'))`

This is because roles is an array of ids that are documents in another table.

Comment: @Zephy If it was in `JavaScript` realm I would add this to the end of query: `... .map(function(result) {
  result.left.server_info = result.rigth;
  return result.left;
 })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `.map(function(row) { return row('left').merge({'server_info': row('right')}); })` to the end of your query to get that effect.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about rethinkdb, but if it is ok for you you can do it with plain Javascript, with [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
var newObject = Object.assign(result[0].left, {server_info: result[0].right)};
```

If you want you can, of course, write the new Object in result itself:

```
result = Object.assign(result[0].left, {server_info: result[0].right)};
```

Comment: RethinkDB already implements this, and it's called `zip`, and the reason why I can't use it is because it will replace the properties with the same name (or keep them in this case).   



Edit: I was referring to the code before the edit, the current one should work.

Comment: @Zephy right, I see now what you want, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all objects in list and add `right` object inside `left` object under `server_info` key/property and then delete `right` object.

```
var arr = [{
"left":{
   "avatar":"a29f54048d9ec6c00913057333160a3e",
   "joined_at":"Thu Feb 25 2016 21:29:07 GMT+00:00",
   "name":"Zephy",
   "uid":"132166948359241728"
},
"right":{
   "icon":"2aab26934e72b4ec300c5aa6cf67c7b3",
   "id":"81384788765712384",
   "member_count":7888,
   "name":"Discord API",
   "owner_id":"53905483156684800",
}
}];

arr.forEach(function(obj){
   obj.left.server_info = obj.right;
   delete obj.right;
});
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to do it directly in the query, but that works too.

Comment: But you pasted javascript code instead of mysql query

Comment: What ? I posted the documents returned by RethinkDB query.